# Google Storage API 1.8.1 - Item getting issue

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-api-dotnet-client

I am not able to get an item through [Google Storage Service API](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/):

```
Google.Apis.Storage.v1.StorageService service;
// ...
Google.Apis.Storage.v1.ObjectsResource.GetRequest request = service.Objects.Get(bucketName, uri);
request.Alt = StorageBaseServiceRequest<GCSObject>.AltEnum.Json;

Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data resp = request.Execute();
```

I am getting GoogleApiException

`"An Error occurred, but the error response could not be deserialized."`

regardless of there specified item exist or not in the storage.

```
"request.ExecuteAsStream()" returns "Not Found" text only.
```

The same issue occurs when trying to set `ObjectAccessControl` through `service.ObjectAccessControls.Insert()` method.

Do you have any suggestions?

P.S. I am able to upload an item though without any problem.

Comment: are you getting the UserCredential correctly?  you haven't included your login code.

Comment: The login code is OK. I am able to insert an item through
ObjectsResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Objects.Insert(bucketName, stream, contentType);
request.Upload();

Comment: I'm just curious: What happen if you remove the line with "request.Alt = ...". And also can you attach the server response in Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler)

Comment: Removing the "request.Alt = ..." does not change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your URI/Object contains characters that need escaping like '/'. 
It might lead (in .NET4) to response not found 404, meaning the object not found on Google cloud. 
The google api for .net cannot serialize this error, so you get this useless message ("error response could not be deserialized").

To fix it, add to the web config:

```
<uri>
<schemeSettings>
<add name="https" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes" />
</schemeSettings>
</uri>
```

I explained the scenario here: [Slash, Google Cloud Storage & .NET4](http://blog.techedup.net/gce-dotnet4/).